# Inline CSS in a Rails web view

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm doing a small Rails project that has very little CSS in it. To save a request, I would like to inline the styling while not losing the comfort of working with SASS.

I know there are a bunch of gems that do it for e-mail views, but is there an easy way to inline CSS in Rails' web views?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding inline CSS to a rails view happens just like adding inline CSS to any other HTML doc.

Inside `users/show.html.erb` you could have

```
<h2 style="font-weight:bold;font-size:28px;"><%= @user.first_name %></h2>
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a tool that does the inlining automatically, keeping the code easy to write, read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

There are gems available for doing the same.
You can use [Premailers-rails](http://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails3), Roadie gem that will convert external CSS to inline CSS.

Answer (score -1):

you should avoid inline CSS for many reasons including robot search, code maintenance, accessibility and more...

I think that 'saving a request' is not a reason to use inline css IMHO.

Comment: I used to agree, until Google started telling me otherwise — specially on mobile websites. I'm looking for a tool that does the inlining automatically, so I the maintenance cost stays as low as possible.